# Postgresql Trigger

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers

```
CREATE TABLE stop_times
(
   trip_id int NOT NULL,
   arrival_time time NOT NULL,
   departure_time time NOT NULL,
   stop_id int NOT NULL,
   stop_sequence int NOT NULL,

   FOREIGN KEY(trip_id) REFERENCES trips,
   FOREIGN KEY(stop_id) REFERENCES stops
);

CREATE TABLE trips
(
   trip_id int NOT NULL,
   trip_name text NOT NULL,
   trip_start time,
   trip_end time,

   PRIMARY KEY(trip_id)
);
```

What I would like to do is after I add/update/delete (a) record(s) to the stop_times table the trips table will update the trip_start as the min(arrival_time) for a group of trip_ids and trip_end as the max(arrival_time) for a group of trip_ids.

Comment: Why do you want to store that information? It can easily be retrieved using a SELECT statement. One rule in a relational database: do not store data that can be derived from other data.

Comment: I thought it would be faster because the data is only going to be update periodically (every month or 2) and stop_times is a relatively large table (about 900,000 rows).

Comment: Go with a view for now, and only optimize it if really gets (too) slow. Do not "assume" something is faster. Test it and then decide. Btw. what is "relatively large" for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, always start with views and tune everything as best as you can with appropriate indexes.  A trigger like this will give you maintenance problems and so you want to avoid it when you can.  Secondly if you have a trigger on something like this and are doing bulk updates, it will make your performance problematic (I know from experience).  It can induce cache misses which can really mess with your ability to insert or update data in bulk.

Secondly, if you need to do this the best option is to have a separate table trip_times and *periodically* materialize data for past trips.  This works best if the data in stop_times is read-only after a certain period of time.